# Handling Multi-Model Conflicts in AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Most AWS Amplify/AppSync tutorials and examples explain how conflict resolution is usually automatic with this tech stack, and in extreme examples show how to custom handle a conflict when saving an instance of a single Model.  What happens when you need to enforce more complicated relationships between your Models, and something goes wrong "down stream"?

**(Contrived) Example:**

Imagine a number of easter eggs holding some number of jelly beans each, and a group of children trying to empty them into their easter baskets.

```
type Child @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  jellybeans: Int!
}

type Egg @model {
  id: ID!
  jellybeans: Int!
}
```

Jellybeans are a conserved quantity - if we add up all the jellybeans across the children and the eggs it should be constant.  Additionally, neither children nor eggs can have "negative jellybeans" - so a CRDT model is not possible.

As the children find eggs, they add them to their baskets:

```
async function findEgg(childId, eggId) {
  const child = await DataStore.query(Child, childId);
  const egg = await DataStore.query(Egg, eggId);

  if (!child || !egg) {
    return;
  }

  const count = egg.jellybeans;

  // Call 1
  await DataStore.save(
    Child.copyOf(child, updated => {
      updated.jellybeans += count;
    })
  );

  // Call 2
  await DataStore.save(
    Egg.copyOf(egg, updated => {
      updated.jellybeans -= count;
    })
  );  
}
```

John, in offline mode, finds egg #ABC, and his app calls `findEgg()` - he got 13 jellybeans!  However, unfortunately, Suzie actually had already found egg #ABC while John was offline, and called `findEgg()`, and AppSync GraphQL had already given her the 13 jellybeans.

I'm not sure what happens here, but I don't think I like it under any circumstances:

- John and Suzie both tried to set #ABC to a count of 0.  AppSync may say "no conflict", while letting John and Suzie both increment their own jellybean count, ruining conservation of jelly beans.
- A conflict was identified and "successfully" resolved as #ABC now has -13 jellybeans.  I can imagine how to identify this and prevent it at the resolver level, so let's skip discussion of that.
- AppSync GraphQL rejects John's Call 2 attempt to update #ABC when John later comes online.  Presumably Call 1 already resolved without issue, though, which is a problem.

**Question Restatement** So - how do you structure the models and/or the code in this contrived example, so that AppSync not only notices an issue, but then also backs out mutations on other models that should not succeed in isolation?

**What I've tried:**

Or rather, not tried, but wondered (because I can't find good examples of this), would be to create something like:

```
type JellybeanTransfer @model {
  child: Child
  egg: Egg
}
```

and then try to save a "new" one of these.  The GraphQL resolver doesn't do a braindead CRUD operation, but instead either (A) saves one of these in addition to updating Child and Egg, all via some sort of BEGIN TRANSACTION / END TRANSACTION sql; or (B) doesn't even create a `JellybeanTransfer` instance anywhere and treats it as a sort of meta/ephemeral concept.  It updates the Child and the Egg, and if it can't do both, backs out the change and rejects the `new JellybeanTransfer`.

Comment: We've got the same issue.

The documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/amplify-datastore-implementation/use-case-and-implementation.html#retail-inventory-counting) gives a similar example - surely they have to combine the subtotals into a correct total?

We tried a custom resolver with a TransactWriteItems but that led to errors warning it was unsupported if versioning was enabled (and surely you want versioning for synchronisation?).  Perhaps you also optimistically update the summaries, storing a from/to value, then you can conflict-resolve to get the right answer?

Comment: Our custom resolver approach is really a variation of your more general approach - you "compress" the transaction into their unit of replication and "decompress" in the resolver.  This is where the lack of TransactWriteItems support hit us.

Comment: Sounds like we did something similar.  I haven't had time to write this as a formal answer, but we ended up going way down the rabbit hole on this and coming up with a solution.  It wasn't too far off from the "(B)" `JellybeanTransfer` approach.  The key was backing the GraphQL Resolver with a Lambda function that let us do whatever we needed to do, and then triggering change event on both the Child and Egg subscription channels.  Not a typical use case in their various docs, makes me want to go make my own DataStore clone that's better...